# How to fix the Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {})

Tags: reactjs

Here is my code:

```
import './NameCell.css';
import RosterTableCell from '../rosterTableCell/RosterTableCell';
function NameCell(props){
    return (
        <RosterTableCell className="nameCell" content={props.content}/>
    )
}
export default NameCell;

//=================================================================================
import NameCell from '../nameCell/NameCell';
function RosterRow(props) {
    return(
        <tr>
            <NameCell content={props.rosterData.itoName}/>
        </tr>
    );
  }
export default RosterRow;
//=================================================================================
import { useEffect,useState} from 'react';
import Roster from '../../../utils/roster';
import RosterRow from './RosterRow';
function TableBody(props){
    const [rosterList, setRosterList] = useState({});
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const getData = async () => {
        let roster = new Roster();
        let rosterData = await roster.get(props.rosterYear, props.rosterMonth);
        let rows=[];
        Object.keys(rosterData).forEach(itoId=>{
          rows.push(<RosterRow rosterData={rosterData[itoId]}/>);
        });
        console.log(rows);       
        setRosterList(rows);
      };
      getData();
    }, [props.rosterYear, props.rosterMonth]);
    return (
        <tbody>
          {rosterList}
        </tbody>
    )
}
export default TableBody;
```

It prompts the following error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead
```

However, the variable rows of TableBody is an array already, why the error still exists?

Comment: change `useState({});` to `useState([]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing your state with an object `{}`.

Use an array.

```
const [rosterList, setRosterList] = useState([]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you set the initial rosterList as an object. Set it to null or empty array should solve the issue.